# Google Place API SDK Country Code - how to?

Tags: android, google-places-api

Using the google Place API Android SDK.
Is there anyway to retrieve the country name / country code from the place object?

It does have in IOS sdk in the address_components but can't find the same element in the Android SDK.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=lati,longi&key=myApiKey

You can parse the JSON from Google Place API
Check below API as well if you are looking for details,

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

OR

Find below code to get current country or pass Lat & Longitude to get country.

```
        public static String getCountryName(Context context, double latitude, double longitude) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses;
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                if (addresses != null && !addresses.isEmpty()) {
                    return addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) { }
            return null;
        }


  [1]: http://
```

Comment: thanks, how about using the sdk or need to use the http request inorder to get the country code?

Comment: @user10198481 Using SDK will be the better option instead of calling the API & fetch the data.                                                                                 String locale =context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();